# How to make \pdfbookmark point to the current line instead of the next line?

Tags: hyperref

I am writing my first latex class file based on article class for homework and exams alike. So I defined a custom sectioning command called `problem`. I try to make each problem visible in the pdf outline. I used the  `hyperref` package and used `\pdfbookmark` to add the custom outlines. One issue is that the command seems to be making the outlined item points to one line below the line the command is issued. Is it normal?

For example, the following is an example where clicking the problem entry in the pdf outline lead to be the line below the first line of problem

```
\newcommand{\problem}{\stepcounter{problem}\vskip\baselineskip\noindent\pdfbookmark[0]{Problem \theproblem}{\theproblem}\textbf{Problem \theproblem.}\enskip}
```

while the following correctly points me to the first line of the problem.

```
\newcommand{\problem}{\stepcounter{problem}\vskip\baselineskip\pdfbookmark[0]{Problem \theproblem}{\theproblem}\noindent\textbf{Problem \theproblem.}\enskip}
```

In the second definition, I basically added the bookmark before entering horizontal mode, while in the first definition, I am adding the bookmark during horizontal mode since I issued the `\noindent` command before it.

### EDIT

According to David Carlisle's answer, LaTeX will put the pdf anchor on the baseline of the line in which the `\pdfbookmark` is called. This statement basically implies what I am experiencing is normal. But he continued that hyperref will try to *deal with this issue* by placing the anchor `\strut` above the baseline of the line the bookmark is called. However, it seems like hyperref only do that in LaTeX headings defined with `\@startsection`, is that true? If so, is there any way to make `\pdfbookmark` make this adjustment in other places where no headings are used? For example, let's say I just want to make a bookmark at a generic place in a paragraph.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, 
    
    but also the leap into electronic\pdfbookmark{mark}{here} typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\clearpage

Just to make the pdf have enough room to scroll down

\end{document}
```

If we compile this, we notice that the bookmark anchor is at the baseline of the first line in the third paragraph. The effect I want is for the anchor to be at the top of that line, i.e., the anchor should appear `\baselineskip` distance above the current distance.

**UPDATE**

I thoght about it a little more today. Let's say you have a paragraph and want to insert a pdf bookmark for that paragraph, then you'd naturally insert the command `pdfbookmark` at the beginning of the paragraph. In this case, we not yet in horizontal mode so the fact that the bookmark is anchored at the baseline before the first line of the paragraph is just what we wanted, i.e., when you click the mark in the pdf viewer, the first line of the paragraph is no scrolled out of view.

But imagine yourself wanting to place a bookmark *inline* (inside a paragraph), the command still insert the anchor at the baseline of that line. But this is now not what you wanted since you want the anchor to be at the baseline of the previous line instead so when you click the bookmark in a pdf viewer, the line where you placed the bookmark is not scrolled out of view.

Maybe one solution is for `hyperref` to recognize whether it is in the middle of a paragraph or not.

Comment: why isn't `\problem` defined  using the latex heading mechanisms? doing it this way doesn't allow `\label` and `\ref` and would allow a page break between the heading and the problem text. the hyperref anchor isn't set on the next line but is set on the baseline so the viewer will put the baseline at the top of the view so the heading is scrolled out of the view.  Hyperref has some code to deal with this basically it tries to insert the anchor the height of a `\strut` above the current point.

Comment: I think the main reason I didn't use `\@startsection` to define `\problem` is because I wanted the section name to appear before the text, and I couldn't figure out a  way to do it without editing the definition of `\@startsection` and without using the `titlesec` package with `explicit` option. Please correct me if I am wrong, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand that comment (and you provide no usable example, and I think(?) you have the fragments in the wrong order since the first has `\noindent`  but you  say it's in the second? `\@startsection` is most likely what you want but even if you need something else (as for example `\chapter` does in the standard classes) you could use `\refstepcounter` so `\label` works, and `\@afterheading` to control page breaks. If you re-used more of the standard mechanisms most likely hyperref would automatically hook into the right place. Too late now I may look tomorrow if no one  has answered

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, indeed a mistype in my question. I will try to play with it more to see if I can get it working.